# Drop multiple columns using UDF - python3

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

I am trying to drop practically half the dataframe using a created function. Be warned, it looks unappealing.

```
def drop_cols(df):
  df.drop(['scrape_id','last_scraped','description','listing_url','neighbourhood','calendar_last_scraped',
           'amenities','neighborhood_overview', 'picture_url','host_url', 'host_about',
           'host_location','host_total_listings_count','host_thumbnail_url','host_picture_url',
           'host_verifications','bathrooms_text','has_availability','minimum_minimum_nights',
           'maximum_minimum_nights','minimum_maximum_nights','maximum_maximum_nights','minimum_nights_avg_ntm',
           'maximum_nights_avg_ntm','number_of_reviews_l30d','calculated_host_listings_count',
           'calculated_host_listings_count_entire_homes','calculated_host_listings_count_private_rooms',
           'calculated_host_listings_count_shared_rooms'],axis=1)
  return df
```

calling the function does not give me any changes. I still have the full dataframe.
Any thoughts? I thought it was a basic indentation issue.

Comment: assign the results back to the df?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Sammy. Inplace = True, proceeding the axis sorted my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the drop method that you’re dropping the columns inPlace (within the same df), or else you need to declare the df again

Add inplace = true after your axis declaration (axis=1) and try again.

Comment: Ill give it a go. 

Fantastic, worked like a charm!

Comment: That’s great! If this answer helped do mark it as accepted

Comment: will do within 5mins (due to timer)